# TextView pushes buttons off screen with HorizontalScrollView

Tags: android, button, textview, scrollview, horizontalscrollview

I am aiming for a layout similar to the native calculator app. I want text to trail off the left of the screen without moving the buttons on the right. Currently my text moves to the left until filling the screen at which point the buttons are pushed off the right edge.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/display_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
    </HorizontalScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/delete_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onDelete"
            android:text="@string/delete_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/equate_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:onClick="onEquate"
            android:text="@string/equate_button" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It looks like part of the layout code you pasted is cut off. The opening LinearLayout tag is not present. An incomplete code snippet can cause confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put your `TextView` into a `HorizontalScrollView`, it will automatically become scrollable when the text exceeds the bounds. See docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:scrollHorizontally

Just add `android:scrollHorizontally="true"` to the `TextView` in the layout.

You may also need to change the text view's layout_weight to 0 or set its layout_width to something fixed (like 100dp).

To get the text to go right-to-left, set the gravity on the TextView to be `android:gravity="right|center_vertical"`

I also humbly refer you the source of the calculator app you are trying to emulate: https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_calculator/tree/master/src

Comment: Your answer does what it says it does. However, the layout that I am trying to achieve pushes the text off the left side of the screen. I've tried android:textDirection="rtl" with no success. The native android calculator app has the exact feature that I want.

Comment: Updated again. I hope this fully answers your question now :)